# Access web page only from verified client

Tags: apache2, openssl, certificate

We have an intranet web based information portal. Now, under development is module for internal orders.

The problem is: When the approver approves the order, it accesses page that requires `https` and accessing it should be much secure than a simple (second) password authentication.

The first idea was to pair certified connection between the server and client, i.e. the server should recognize that client has installed appropriate certificate, otherwise, to show inaccessible page message.
We played with OpenSSL certificates, but because we are newbie in that, there was no success.

**Which is the right way to do this?**

Probably, this is important: The certificates was done under Linux. They should work on Win2003 server with installed Apache2 with enabled SSL module (PHP, MySQL). Also - pages can be accessed only via IP address of the server. *Is it OK to configure certificate for IP address?* Information we used to generate certificates is [here](http://kamenitza.org/archives/239).

**Is there another way to secure connection between client and server in that case, i.e. to ensure that only privileged client (computer, browser) is accessing the secured page?** If you have other suggestions, they will be well appriciated.

Comment: The certificates is good way to go. You just need to issue and install correct certificates to all legit users. Goot information is here (it's for PHP but most of the setup is general / in apache/openssl)

Comment: Hi Kamil. Where is the information? I didn't see the link.

Comment: Eh, my fault :-) here you go: http://cweiske.de/tagebuch/ssl-client-certificates.htm

Comment: Hi again. Thanks for the link. [Here](http://www.cafesoft.com/products/cams/ps/docs30/admin/ConfiguringApache2ForSSLTLSMutualAuthentication.html) there appears useful info.